# Set values ofelements in an array by field name c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an array of two rows ,each row looks like this with variation in data. 
[image]

And I am querieng the FieldValue from this array like this

```
 var objlinkedin = myarray.Where(r => r.FieldName == "LinkedIn Profil").Select(m => m.FieldValue).ToList();
```

Now I want to set the `FieldValue` of the row to "myvalue" where `FieldName="LinkedIn Profil"` what is the correct way to make this?..

Comment: Please post your sample data in the question, do not use images.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici thanks for the tip..I will remember in future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To *change* the value, you'd need the parent object, i.e.

```
foreach(var obj in myarray.Where(r => r.FieldName == "LinkedIn Profil"))
{
    obj.FieldValue = "myvalue";
}
```

You can simplify if you know there will be zero-or-one hits, note. Indeed, if you expect zero-or-one, it might be worth indexing them into a dictionary:

```
fields = myarray.ToDictionary(x => x.FieldName);
```

then later:

```
SomeType found;
if(fields.TryGetValue("LinkedIn Profil", out found)) {
    found.FieldValue = "myvalue";
}
```

Comment: I have completely understood the first part with a loop..But after that I am unable to follow up..It would be really great if you could explain the dictionary part little more ..

Comment: @AthulKSurendran the dictionary just avoids you having to loop each time - it is an index, using the field-name as a key